# How do I decrease the size of the page file?

Tags: windows, pagefile

I just upgraded my laptop RAM to 12GB (W510, 4 DIMM slots), and since I am using a SSD, I find hard drive space to be quite precious. However, since I have more than enough RAM for most stuff, I think I can get by with probably around 4GB of page file. however, on C drive, there is a `pagefile.sys` which I assume to be reserving space for page files in the OS, how would I decrease the size of this file?

Answer (score 36):

To adjust the pagefile size, press <kbd>Windows Flag Key</kbd>+<kbd>Pause/Break</kbd>.

From here, on the left hand side, choose `Advanced system settings`, this will open `System Properties on the`Advanced tab`.

Next click on `Settings` in the `Performance` Group.

Now click the `Advanced` tab.

Next click `Change` under `Virtual Memory`

And, deselect `Automatically manage paging file size for all drives`, and then click `Custom size` and change it whatever you want.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can decrease the size of the page file, but see [this warning from Microsoft first](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2860880/how-to-determine-the-appropriate-page-file-size-for-64-bit-versions-of):

> 64-bit versions of Windows and Windows Server support more physical memory (RAM) than 32-bit versions support. However, the reason to configure the page file size has not changed. **It has always been about supporting a system crash dump, if it is necessary**, or extending the system commit limit, if it is necessary.  For example, when a lot of physical memory is installed, a page file might not be required to back the system commit charge during peak usage. The available physical memory alone might be large enough to do this. However, a page file or a dedicated dump file might still be required to back a system crash dump.

The reason your page file is the same size as your RAM isn't for performance; it's in case Windows needs it for a crash dump.

Answer (score 0):

> When Windows creates pagefile.sys it
>   typically makes it a "large" size -
>   usually the size of RAM installed on
>   your machine.

Take a look at this to change the size of the file: [What is pagefile.sys and can I move it?](http://ask-leo.com/what_is_pagefilesys_and_can_i_move_it.html) It should help you to change the size of it.