# How can I shrink my 12GB pagefile.sys?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, memory, pagefile

Even though I only have 4GB of RAM, I have a 12GB pagefile.sys. From what I've read about the topic, this is bigger than the x1.5 rule-of-thumb and it's also taking a huge chunk of space on my hard drive. I tend to run a lot of applications and tabs withing web browsers, so the last time this happened, I closed everything down and restarted my computer. When I ran WinDirStat again later the pagefile was down to 3-4GB. Now my pagefile is up to 12GB again and closing programs/restarting is not working.

My first question is what actions cause pagefile.sys to grow so large in relation to the installed RAM (computer on for long amounts of time, too many programs running, too many browser tabs open)? Second, how can I get my pagefile.sys down to 6-7GB?

I'm running Windows 7 Home Premium SP1 with 4GB of RAM

Comment: Is the current setting to allow Windows to manage the size pagefile  or have you configured it to be a specific size.  Of course if Windows is creating a 12GB then it should to be that large.

Comment: Part of the problem is you have so little RAM for the number of programs your using.  When Windows runs out of REAL memory it uses swap file and it uses more and more swap file until its needs are met.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I decrease the size of the page file?](https://superuser.com/questions/292989/how-do-i-decrease-the-size-of-the-page-file)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can manually limit the pagefile size by performing the following steps:

1. Click on the **Start** button.
2. Right click on **Computer**.
3. Select **Properties**
4. Click on **Advanced system settings** on the left.
5. Click on the **Settings** button under the **Performance** group.
6. Select the **Advanced** tab of the **Performance Options** window.
7. Click on the **Change** button.
8. Uncheck **Automatically manage paging file size for all drives**.
9. Select the **C:** drive in the list.
10. Check the **Custom size** radio button.
11. Enter the **Initial** and **Maximum** sizes you want to use. I would recommend 4096 MB for the Initial and 6144 MB for the Maximum.
12. Click **OK** on the **Virtual Memory** dialog.
13. Click **OK** on the **Performance Options** dialog.
14. Click **OK** on the **System Properties** dialog.

Comment: So, multiply your GB of RAM by 1024 for the **Initial** and multiply that result by 1.5 for the **Maximum**?

Answer (score 9):

You can force a Virtual Memory file size by:

1. Left click on 'Start'.
2. Right click on 'PC'.
3. Left click on 'Properties'.
4. Left click on 'Advanced system configuration'.
5. If needed, left click on 'OK'.
6. Select 'Advanced options' tab.
7. Left click on 'Configuration' inside 'Throughput'.
8. Select 'Advanced options' tab.
9. Left click on 'Change' inside 'Virtual memory'.
10. Edit your preferences.
11. Close all the opened windows by accepting.

Comment: This sounds like very specific instructions for some OS version other than Windows 7. Are you sure this isn't for Vista, or Windows 8?

Comment: No, not at all.

Comment: There is no 'Configuration' button or 'Throughput' group on the 'Advanced' tab.

Comment: I might have been guessing from five to nine. Upvoters please upvote [more exact answer](http://superuser.com/a/1029104/174140) too.

Answer (score 0):

If you have more than one partition, follow the steps indicated by uprego in his answer but also:

- set the swap file to another partition (e.g. so no swap file parts on C:, all on D:)
- reboot
- do the same again setting the swap file back
  -reboot

This will recreate the swap file with your initial settings, so you can always force its size down this way (any fragmentation in the file will be removed).
But it does not remove the cause of the big file; you will have to figure that out from other clues. As you already suggested, you probably have a lot of programs open at the same time, a lot of browser tabs, or you use memory-hungry applications.

BTW If you just want to remove fragmentation in the swap file use SysInternals' [pagedefrag](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897426.aspx)

Comment: pagedefrag doesn't work on 64-bit Windows, which I sadly found out just yesterday.