# Hard disk use has skyrocketed after Windows 8 updates

Tags: windows, windows-update

I've been using Windows 8 on my computer for 3 months. After applying the system updates, the hard disk usage has gone from 15GB to 26GB. What happened to my laptop? Is there anything I can do to free space on my HD?

Comment: How big is your hard drive, and is it an SSD?

Comment: It have 350gb but i spend only 30gb for C: to installing window 8 and other softwares.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/292989/how-do-i-decrease-the-size-of-the-page-file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows will take up more space over time as it downloads additional updates.  That said, [you may have some temporary files you can clean up](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/delete-files-using-disk-cleanup).

While there are many "disk cleaner" programs out there, only you know what you really want to keep, and what you can get rid of.

I rather like windirstat https://windirstat.info for a program which will show you graphically what is taking up your disk.

Start with that, and see if you have any files you've forgotten about taking up space.

Comment: @screener - That is a useful link, but it addresses a different aspect of the question than this answer is focused on and makes a different point.  Its value is lost if people don't realize that it's different from the answer and click on it.  You should turn that into a separate answer.

Comment: @fixer1234 How is a link on how to clean up your hard disk different from the text that says "you may have some temporary files you can clean up"? If you've ever read computer guides before, or texts on the Internet in general, different sections link to different relevant links.

Comment: @screener - In this answer, the mention of having temporary files to clean up is just a setup to discuss the point of using a tool to help make personal decisions about what to clean up file-by-file based on space usage.  The link focuses on tools to clean up in a more automated way based on classes of files.  They are two different approaches with different application.  Both are important.  They should either be separate, focused answers, which could net you some rep, or this answer should be expanded to explicitly address both points rather than hide the second subject in a link.